# For cone $x^2 = y^2 + z^2$, how to set up Triple Integral along $x$-Axis to Find Volume

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Set up an integral to compute the volume of the solid inside the cone
> $x^2 = y^2 + z^2$, with $|x| \geq  1$, in a coordinate system of
> your choice.

Since the cone is along the $x$-axis, I'm not sure how to set up my triple integral. I cannot use rectangular, spherical, or cylindrical, because the shadow/projection I'd use to find the bounds would be in the $xz$-plane. How should I solve this? TIA

Comment: use whichever coordinate system is best, just swap the equations for $x$ and $z$. Is there any rule that says you can't?

Comment: Should I use a double integral instead with the based on the xz projection?

Comment: Personally I think it's easier to organize as a triple integral, but either works.

Comment: Cylindrical: $r^2=y^2+z^2$ with $dydz=rdrd\theta$.  The statement looks funny?  $|x|\ge 1$ leads to infinite cone.